# JavaScript Unsafe Access?

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, canvas, https

When trying to use JavaScript in my app I am getting these following errors from Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
>
> _I-bZ2aLo8f.js:48
>
> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
> http://apps.facebook.com/ubo-elementalfury/ from frame with URL
> https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=17#channel=f2f2ee12fc&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fultimate-battle-online.com&channel_path=%2Fchannel.php%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df3312304ec%26.
> The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being
> accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.
>
> xd_arbiter.php:20

I am not sure what is going on, I don't get this issue when browsing it from a secure Facebook connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unsafe access error isn't causing your problem. Its the extra parenthesis you have. Go through your code and find where that is and remove it, then see what happens.

It would be helpful to know what section of your FB app that is causing this.

Edit:

I see other issues in your app that aren't related to this. In your app, http://ultimate-battle.com, on the Choose your Clan page you have this line:

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=movingtime;
```

#clock doesn't exist on this page. The error is in jquery.mycode.js on line 419.

Comment: That isn't a file that I wrote however.

Comment: You haven't really provided any actionable code examples to work with though. That error looks like the extra parens is in Facebook's js file.

Comment: Yeah looks like this only happens when you are not using HTTPS, I will be filing a bug report with Facebook developers, and thanks for the tip on the above code.

Comment: Facebook's code does most likely *not* contain an extra paren, instead, this is an example of a corruption issue seen in Chrome. Empty your cache and you will see it disappear.